websocket-sharp change byte order in WebSocket.Send
While experimenting with different websocket implementations for C# .NET, I noticed that they send audio data as byte arrays with different byte order:

ClientWebSocket.SendAsync (from System.Net.Sockets default .NET library) uses little-endian byte order

WebSocket.SendAsync (from websocket-sharp NuGet library) uses big-endian byte order

WatsonWsClient.Send (from WatsonWebsocket NuGet library) also uses big-endian byte order


I'm sure the array was staying the same (I'm pushing to the socket exactly what I'm getting from an audio device), I was just changing the websocket implementation.
The question is can I change the byte order while using websocket-sharp library? Besides that small issue everything is great with the library.

The concept of endianness applies to numeric values, not to byte arrays. So what numeric value is there in a WebSocket frame? The payload length only AFAIK. I find it hard to believe such claim, especially since the RFC explicitely says it has to be big endian. It would literally make System.Net.Sockets simply broken. Like ultimately broken, the other side would not be able to decode the frame correctly. But if you see the order of bytes in payload reversed (which is how I read your question) then this is a problem in some other part of your code. Probably with serialization.

Sorry, you're right about endianness. So I'm getting audio data from a WASAPI audio device (as a byte array) and pushing the same data to different websockets. Without changing the data and without changing anything on the server, what server receives looks different for different websockets in terms of endianness.
